# how to use JdSoft.Apple.Apns.Notifications in my monotouch project

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Any body please tell me how to use [JdSoft.Apple.Apns.Notifications](https://github.com/Redth/APNS-Sharp) in my mono touch project ?

Or else please suggest me another way to create push notifications ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the compiled assemblies of JdSoft.Apple.Apns.Notifications and reference them in your project. Then take a look at the samples how to send notifications.

Keep in mind that this needs to be done in a server application that receives push notification subscribers and maintains it's own subscriber table. Then you send push notifications from the server application to the subscribers using JdSoft.Apple.Apns.Notifications.